# Validation with DataAnnotations in Azure shows wrong Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, resources, translation, data-annotations

We creating a windows azure website in MVC4 and we are using dataannotation to set the display-name and also to validate the input fields. It is a multilanguage page and thus we are unsing Resource-Files to translate.

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(GlobalResource), Name = "LitZip")]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrRequiredZip")]
public string ZIP { get; set; }
```

Local all works perfect. Uploaded on windows azure all shows fine too but the errors after validation are not translated. When I'm returning the CurrentCulture, it's correctly set to german. We are using the custom tool "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" to generate the resource files.

Hope anybody can help us with this issue.

thanks in advance!

kind reagrds

Edit:
The culture is set by a filterattribute as follows:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("de-de");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Edit 2013-05-02:

I'm currently setting the culture in the ActionFilterAttribute. When I set the culture in the web.config-File it all works.

```
<globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE" />
```

Nevertheless, I need to be able to change the culture on runtime individual for the users. Maybe the ActionFilterAttribute is the wrong position here? I need to access cookie data..

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to set the culture?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to Web.Config file.

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto:ru-RU" culture="auto:ru-RU" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```